# How to write a comment with Emmet plugin in Sublime?

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets, emmet

Im using sublime 2 with Emmet plugin. Is there a way to write a comment with speed coding that would produce me something like that:

```
<div class="container">
   Lorem ipsum
</div> <!-- custom comment -->
```

I've tried

div.container

And it's not working.

Is it possible to add comments to each div or element created via speed coding snippets?

Comment: http://docs.emmet.io/filters/#comment-tags-c

Answer (score 16):

You can write quick comand c+tab for simple comment or you can write in this form c{my comment}+tab to add text into de comment tags

Answer (score 1):

Use filters:

```
div>div#page>p.title+p|c
```

Reference: http://docs.emmet.io/filters/

Answer (score 1):

**`c>{some comment}` will give you a comment with text "some comment" in it.**

To have a comment after a `div`, you can use the following:

```
div.container+c{custom comment}
```

[image]

If you also want to have some text inside the div, you can use the following:

```
div.container{Hello World}+c>{custom comment}
```

[image]

If you want to have something after the comment, you need to group it using brackets as shown below:

```
div.container{Hello World}+(c>{custom comment})+div#nav
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

> c{test}+div>p{Comments!}^c{/test}